# assembly print n-digits number

Tags: winapi, assembly, printing

i apologize for every mistake i could have done with english (it's not my mother language).

I've tried to print a number greater than 9. I've divided it to take every digits and then i print them one by one.
The code works, but it also print others characters, before giving error and stop working.

Here the code:

```
.386 
.model flat,stdcall 
option casemap:none 
include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\user32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
.data
    textNum dd "c",0                                            ;variable i use to display every single digit (initialized with a casual character)
    num dd 25678                                                ;number to print
    divisor dd 10
.code
    start:
        mov eax, num
        xor ecx,ecx                                             ;ecx is the digits counter
        lea esi, textNum                                        ;mov in esi the adress of textNum
        ciclo:
            cmp eax,0                                           ;when the dividend is 0 exit
            jbe print

            xor edx,edx                                         ;reset edx to take the remainder
            div divisor
            push edx                                            ;push the remainder

            add cl,1                                            ;increase digits counter
            jmp ciclo

        print:
            cmp cl,0                                            ;since the counter is greater than 0
            jbe return

            xor eax,eax
            pop eax                                             ;pop in eax the digit i want to print
            add eax,48                                          ;add 48 (ascii value)
            mov [esi], eax                                      ;move the digit inside the variable

            invoke StdOut, addr textNum                         ;print the variable

            sub cl, 1                                           ;dec counter
            jmp print
        return:
            invoke ExitProcess, 0
    end start
```

[Here a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEfGz.png)

The number is correct, but there is much more stuff after that... Why does it happens and how could i avoid it?

EDIT:
I've also tried to use an array without changing the rest of the code. The first element is the one i change, and the second one is the terminator character(always 0):

```
;textNum dd "c",0                                            ;variable i use to display every single digit (initialized with a casual character)
textNum dd 2 dup(0)
```

But it is still giving problems

Comment: Presumably your `StdOut` function expects a zero terminated string but you don't zero terminate.

Comment: *"`;when the dividend is 0 exit`"* describes what should happen. `jbe print` however keeps printing. That should probably be `je return`.

Comment: I've already tried to use je but the output is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to change the register used as a counter (ecx) with edi and now it works. Maybe StdOut uses ecx and changes his value